# Ubuntu 22.04 OVH failover IP netplan config? Gateway4 depreceated

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, proxmox

I've had no issues setting up a ubuntu 20.04 server on my proxmox server that's hosted on an OVH box using this guide,

https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002394324-How-to-Connect-a-VM-to-the-Internet-Using-Proxmox-VE#ubuntu

However when I try to use this on 22.04 ubuntu, I get the gateway4 is depreceated error after I netplan apply. I still could connect but I'd like to fix this error.

````
   ```network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
          ens160:
                  dhcp4: no
                  dhcp6: no
                  addresses: [FAILOVERIP/32]
                  gateway4: BOX'S IP
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220]
                  routes:
                  - to: BOXES IP/32
                    via: 0.0.0.0
                    scope: link
````

I used this, replacing to: and gateway4 with my boxes address, and the addresses to my failover IP.

How could I fix this to rid the error I'm receiving?

What I tried was changing it "to: default" and "via: SERVER BOX'S IP" however that does not work.

How could I fix this to get my network, working with the proper  netplan config????

Answer (score 0):

As per this [U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681220/netplan-generate-gateway4-has-been-deprecated-use-default-routes-instead), the `routes:` block covers what it needs to do, and you replace it with a

```
routes:
      - to: default
        via: BOXES IP/32
```

or whatever interface talks to the outside world.

Comment: I've actually tried this, the instructions calls for box's IP.254/32

And this hasn't worked either.